# How do I get rid of this crease when joining/creating new faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

So I'm trying to create the face of a character model by starting around the eyes and mouth but when I try and join the edges to connect it creates this weird crease. I want to smooth it out but I can't seem to get rid of it.

What I'm doing is pressing F with the selected vertices to create a new face to connect and this happens.

[image]

Any help to getting rid of it is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: maybe the normals are flipped?

Comment: Hello :). This looks like flipped faces meeting correct faces. You can simply check and correct the orientation.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Dont create a single face with F.

Select all the edges you want to join (in both parts you want to join) and use the Bridge Edge Loops command (you can easily find it with the F3 seach menu).